# How do I fix this dependency issue in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, jackson, dependencies, leiningen, amazonica

I'm having a lot of trouble fixing an issue where the dependencies for two different packages are colliding. My project.clj's dependencies look like this:

```
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [itsy "0.1.1"]  
                 [amazonica "0.3.22" :exclusions [commons-logging org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core]]])
```

My namespace looks like this:

```
(ns crawler.core
  (:require [itsy.core :refer :all])
  (:require [itsy.extract :refer :all])
  (:use  [amazonica.core]
         [amazonica.aws.s3]))
```

When I try to load the namespace into lein's repl with `(load crawler/core)`, I get this error:

```
CompilerException java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z, compiling:(amazonica/core.clj:1:1)
```

Online sources suggest that this is a dependency mismatch. How do I fix it?

Comment: could you include the part of the output from running "lein deps :tree" that mentions either itsy or amazonica. there will most likely be a suggested exclusion in the output as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the exclusion on itsy rather than amazonica and it worked. Also fixed the NS form in core.clj.

project.clj:

```
(defproject blabla "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
   :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
   :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [itsy "0.1.1" :exclusions [com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core]]  
                  [amazonica "0.3.22" :exclusions [commons-logging org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient]]])
```

core.clj:

```
(ns blabla.core
  (:require [itsy.core :refer :all]
            [itsy.extract :refer :all]
            [amazonica.core :refer :all]
            [amazonica.aws.s3 :refer :all]))

(defn foo
   "I don't do a whole lot."
  [x]
   (println x "Hello, World!"))
```

to deal with these situatuions in general run

lein deps :tree

and add exclusions until only the newest versions remain.

Comment: Thanks Arthur. I'll try this later tonight. I actually did do what you suggest regarding running lein deps :tree and adding in exclusions until it stopped making suggestions. That's how I got to the above.